# How to use Redim Preserve in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub C()
    
    Dim V
    
    For K = 7 To C_Count
      If 0 < Cells(9, K) And Cells(9, K) < 100 Then
        lngV = lngV + 1
        ReDim Preserve V(lngV)
        V(lngV) = Cells(9, K)
      End If
    
    Next
End Sub
```

I wanted to add a value to the array only when the Cells(9,k) is over 0 and under 100, but an error occurs with that code. Could someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: "an error occurs" doesn't tell us much about exactly what happens when you run this.  What is the exact error, and on which line?

Comment: I think you need to declare (DIM) your variable as an array first

Comment: Where do you assign value of C_Count?

Comment: Using `ReDim Preserve` in a loop gives your code quadratic complexity. A better option (it you aren't able to allocate all at once) is to use an [ArrayList](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/). It isn't native to VBA, but VBA code can use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `ReDim Preserve`

- You need to declare the variable using parentheses to be able to 'apply' the first `ReDim Preserve` on it: `Dim V() As Variant`
- Note that this can be written to be more efficient i.e. by creating a reference to the row range and using its number of columns to `ReDim` the array. In the end, only one or none `ReDim Preserve` is needed.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteToZeroBasedArray()
    
    Dim V() As Variant ' Note the parentheses!
    Dim Index As Long
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = 10 ' e.g.
    
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 7 To cCount
        If 0 < Cells(9, c).Value And Cells(9, c).Value < 100 Then
            ReDim Preserve V(Index)
            ' A safer way (Option Base related):
            'ReDim Preserve V(0 To Index)
            V(Index) = Cells(9, c).Value
            Index = Index + 1
        End If
    Next c
    
    If Index = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Debug.Print Join(V, vbLf)

End Sub
    
Sub WriteToOneBasedArray()
    
    Dim V() As Variant ' Note the parentheses!
    Dim Index As Long
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = 10 ' e.g.
    
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 7 To cCount
        If 0 < Cells(9, c).Value And Cells(9, c).Value < 100 Then
            Index = Index + 1
            ReDim Preserve V(1 To Index)
            V(Index) = Cells(9, c).Value
        End If
    Next c
    
    If Index = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Debug.Print Join(V, vbLf)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! It really helped me a lot!!